# Synergy connection error

Tags: synergy

Today I got the warning:
"ipc connection error, remote host closed". 
Ii was under Windows Server 2008 and Synergy 1.8.7, but after updateing to 1.8.8 the same warning.
No Firewall active, the client with Win 10 is always searching for connection?

Is there anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I had this and spent too many hours trying to sort it trying all the tips I could find including removing my firewall. Eventually I used a third party uninstaller then made a copy of my Registry and manually deleted all references to Synergy. Reinstalled Synergy (Server) and away it went no problems without even needing to reboot. This was on Windows7 64 bit.
Note: You edit the Registry at your own risk!